# How do I search through a folder for the filename that matches a regular expression using Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am having some difficulty writing a function that will search through a directory for a file that matches a specific regular expression (which I have compiled using 're.compile'). So my question is: How do I search through a directory (I plan to use os.walk) for a file that matches a specific regular expression? An example would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296173/how-do-i-copy-files-with-specific-file-extension-to-a-folder-in-my-python-versi

Comment: I would like to know specifically how to use the re module to search through a directory and isolate the file/s (in this case file) matching the regular expression I've compiled. Thanks to SO, I am able to traverse a directory. But not sure how to pick out the file with the right pattern.Make sense?

Comment: @Amara:  Sorry, but question is still too general.  "pickout out a file with the right pattern" should be obvious.  For some reason it's not obvious, yet.  You'll have to be very specific about what you don't understand.  Otherwise, you're just asking us to do your homework.

Comment: @S.Lott: Ok. I'll work on that. Thanks for the honest feedback. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will find all files starting with two digits and ending in gif, you can add the files into a global list, if you wish:

```
import re
import os
r = re.compile(r'\d{2}.+gif$')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/vinko'):
  l = [os.path.join(root,x) for x in files if r.match(x)]
  if l: print l #Or append to a global list, whatever
```

Comment: Your regexp also matches 'a.gif.bak' which is not ending with 'gif'.

Comment: You should use `match` not `search`.

Comment: fnmatch.filter(files, '*.gif') will do just fine. A better example would be r'(?i)Merlin.*?s(\d{2})e(\d{2}).*?(?:avi|mkv)$'.

Comment: @S.Lott: why? 
@J.F. Sebastian: Right. That's a better example.

Comment: About search() v/s match(). As far as I can tell, it depends on how are you going to write your regex. search() will return a match if there is a match anywhere in the string, whereas match will return a match only from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read about the [RE](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-re.html) pattern's `match` method.
2. Read all answers to [How do I copy files with specific file extension to a folder in my python (version 2.5) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296173/how-do-i-copy-files-with-specific-file-extension-to-a-folder-in-my-python-versi)?
3. Pick one that uses `fnmatch`.  Replace `fnmatch` with `re.match`.  This requires careful thought.  It's not a cut-and-paste.
4. Then, ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern you have to match is simple enough to grab with filesystem wildcards, I recommend you take a look at the glob module, which exists for this exact purpose.