# Python development - elementtree XML and string operations

Tags: python, django, elementtree

I am using [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) to load up a series of XML files and parse them. As a file is parsed, I am grabbing a few bits of data from it ( a headline and a paragraph of text).  I then need to grab some file names that are stored in the XML. They are contained in an element called `ContentItem`.

My code looks a bit like this:

```
for item in dirlist:
    newsML = ET.parse(item)
    NewsLines = newsML.getroot()
    HeadLine = NewsLines.getiterator("HeadLine")
    result.append(HeadLine)
    p = NewsLines.getiterator("p")
    result.append(p)
    ci = NewsLines.getiterator("ContentItem")
    for i in ci:
        result.append(i.attrib)
```

Now, if there was only one type of file, this would have been fine, but it contains 3 types (jpg, flv and a mp4). So as I loop through them in the view, it spits them out, but how do I just grab the flv if I only want that one? or just the mp4? They don't always appear in the same order in the list either.

Is there a way to say if it ends in .mp4 then do this action, or is there a way to do that in the template even?

If i try to do this;

```
        url = i.attrib
        if url.get("Href", () ).endswith('jpg'):
            result.append(i.attrib)
```

I get an error tuple object has no attribute endswith. Why is this a tuple? I thought it was a dict?

Comment: What about `.endswith()` (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) or `.splitext()` (http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)?

Comment: Step 1: search for everyone else with the same filename matching problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+filename+match  Step 2: Pick a similar question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296173/how-do-i-copy-files-with-specific-file-extension-to-a-folder-in-my-python-versio.  Step 3: Read what others have done.

Comment: That's not the same thing im trying to do. I just want to match against some text in an elements attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a tuple because you supply a tuple (the parentheses) as the default return value for `url.get()`. Supply an empty string, and you can use its `.endswith()` method. Also note that the element itself has a `get()` method to retrieve attribute values (you do not have to go via `.attrib`). Example:

```
if i.get('Href', '').endswith('.jpg'):
    result.append(i.attrib)
```