# Copy files (as backup) and change original file names (rearranging contents)

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-processing, file-rename, shutil

i'm a total python noob but i want to learn it and integrate it to my workflow.

I have about 400 files containing 4 different parts in the filename separated by an underline: 
-> Version_Date_ProjectName_ProjectNumber

As we allways look at the Projectnumber first, we arranged the contents of the filename for new projects to: 
-> ProjectNumber_Version_ProjektName

My Problem now is, that i like to rename all the existing files to be rearranged to the new format while having them backed up in a subdirectory called "Archiv".

It just has to be a simple script that i put in the directory and every file in this directory will be copied as backup and changed to the new filename.

EDIT:

My first step was to create a subfolder within the source directory, and it worked somehow. But no i saw, that i just need to backup the files with a specific file extension.

```
import os, shutil

src_dir= os.curdir
dst_dir= os.path.join(os.curdir, "Archiv")

shutil.copytree(src_dir, dst_dir)
```

i tried to extend the code with the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296173/how-do-i-copy-files-with-specific-file-extension-to-a-folder-in-my-python-versi) but it doesn't work out. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil  
import glob

src_path = "YOU_SOURCE_PATH"
dest_path = "YOUR DESTINATION PATH"

if not os.path.exists(dest_path):
    os.makedirs(dest_path)

files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.pdf"))
for file in files:
if os.path.isfile(file):
    shutil.copy2(file, dest_path)
```

Comment: But you most search more in future :) . I learn python my self, But never ask question in Stack, Because it has a very good and powerful Documentation.But I will  answer you any time:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem here ist, that i need to create a subfolder in the source directory and then copy all the files in there.

I managed to do that with 

import os, shutil

src_dir= os.curdir
dst_dir= os.path.join(os.curdir, "Archiv")

shutil.copytree(src_dir, dst_dir)

But now i see that i need to copy just the files with a specic file extension and thats where i struggle now.^^

Comment: I edited the post, So if you chang "pdf" with your extention type, it most work good.